# When to use named pipes in Windows?

Tags: windows, named-pipes

In *nix many command line applications that accept file names as arguments accept pipes also. Example:

```
anApplication file.txt
```

Also works with

```
anApplication | anotherApplication arguments
```

And the result of the "anotherApplication" is redirected to "anApplication" as it was a file

I learned that the Windows equivalent to this is a "named pipe". I wonder if the command line application must be aware of named pipes to understand it, or if any command line application that accepts a file as argument would work with a named pipe instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've got this quite backwards. Just to be precise:

```
anApplication file.txt
```

This runs `anApplication` with the filename `file.txt` as the first command line argument.

```
anApplication | anotherApplication arguments
```

This runs `anApplication` with no command line arguments. The standard out is connected to the standard in of `anotherApplication` which is run with `arguments` as the command line arguments. This is exactly the same on windows as it is on Unix versions. Named pipes are a completely different OS feature.

A named pipe is a directory entry that looks like a file, but acts like a stream of data that you can attach output and input to.

Answer (score 6):

A [named pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590(VS.85).aspx) on Windows is a very different thing than what you're talking about. A named pipe is actually a tool for helping to build server applications on Windows, and is roughly equivalent to a "Unix domain socket".

In your situation, whether `anApplication` works in this situation depends on how the application reacts when executed without a file name on the command line. (I'm talking about the arrangement in your description; the command line is backwards as pointed out by another answer.) If the application reads from `stdin` when started without a command line, then this sort of shell pipe arrangement will work. If instead, the application prints a help message and exits when started without a file name, then this shell pipe will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is the syntax of cmd.exe.

This sort of pipe redirection should work with any program, **so to answer your specific question, the program needs no special code if it is a standard console application.**

*There is one caveat - if the program is getting input through the special keyboard monitoring forms of runtime API, then redirection won't work.*

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it works the same under Windows as in UNIX. I suppose that some more advanced Win32 Console API functions might bypass this, but you'll have to read the documentation for that.